# Weird Magento 500 Internal Server Errors

Tags: php, apache, magento, magento-1.9, internal-server-error

I run a Magento 1.9.2.4 app and I made some updates in my server through WHM today, after that I'm getting the "Error 500".

The weird thing is that this error not appears all time. For exemple, if I open the same page in different tabs, in a row, 10 times, about 4 of these 10 tabs will get the error 500. What this might be?

I also enabled the errors log through php.ini configurations, but I'm not getting a specific new information

**The updates that I made:**

**Some new apache modules installed:**

• mod_file_cache

• mod_http2

**PHP Changes:**

• Updated php5.4 to php5.5, and I uninstalled the php5.4 after this

• php55-php-opcache installed

• php55-php-zendguard UNinstalled

---

What change could have caused this?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: checking apache logs, would be the first step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem just enabling the PHP-FPM.

Answer (score 1):

You can check errors in support_report.log file as well.

If you find any layout xml is not being loaded completely then the 500 error could occur.

If that is the issue then you can add below code into app/bootstrap.php and try same scenario.

```
if (function_exists('libxml_disable_entity_loader')) {
    libxml_disable_entity_loader(false);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! Where can I find the support_report.log  ?